how do I effectively use the knife tool for fine detail near the edges of a beveled object
I'm currently working on modeling the midsole of a shoe.  I'd like the midsole to have line-indentions on the side of the midsole.  I tried subdividing the object a bunch and then using the draw sharp tool with the sharp falloff, but it wasn't giving me the effect that I wanted.  Instead, I decided to keep it not subdivided and use the knife tool to create the lines, bevel them to the thickness I was looking for, then extrude them inward.  This produced something closer to the effect I was looking for, but it ending up making some discrepancies in the mesh near the end of the lines.  I've tried filling in the parts of the mesh that have unconnected squares, to no avail.  I think I just need some advice for the best way to go about this.
This is the view of the discrepancies in the mesh

This is what the mesh looks like on the inside:


Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

My first instinct would be to give those slits a little bit more room from the bottom of the shoe,  like move the part that actually touches the ground away slightly and also maybe add another edge loop running parallel to the sole.

Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "this","issue with" or "question about". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See "What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Also, please avoid using phrases like 'need tips' as this sounds opinion-based and is off-topic. This will help prevent your question from being closed.

I figured it out- basically, I just needed to clean up and simplify the structure of my mesh, while not having my knife cuts extend to the outer edge of the midsole, instead, connecting to an additional edge loop just inside the outer edge.
